# UINavigationController and large titles when popping ViewController

Tags: uinavigationcontroller, uikit, uinavigationbar

I have a `UINavigationController` which has its `navigationBar` configured to `prefersLargeTitles = true` and `isTranslucent = false`.

The first view controller in the navigation stack is a `UITableViewVontroller` with its `navigationItem` configured as `largeTitleDisplayMode = .always`. If I push a further view controller with `largeTitleDisplayMode = .never` and pop it again, the first view controller is in a state where the large title is collapsed. I have to scroll up to enlarge the title again.

Is this intentional behaviour of iOS 14? Is there a way to restore the large title?

Edit: I just realized, that the behaviour is tied to the `isTranslucent` property of the navigation bar.

Comment: What did you do to get this to work properly @mschmidt? I'm having the same issue even with my isTranslucent set to true.

Comment: There seems to be no reliable way to prevent this behavior. During testing it seemed that setting `isTranslucent` to `true` for all view controllers helps most of the time. I did ship my App with the problem unfixed.

Comment: I think I found a solution for this. Apparently, if you are using UINavigationBarAppearance objects to customize your navigationController / navigationBar, don't. Instead just use the navigationController?.navigationBar properties and make sure you set largeTitleTextAttributes and titleTextAttributes after prefersLargeTitles and isTranslucent. That's what fixed my issue @mschmidt.

Comment: Thanks, I will investigate this.